# Angular: Can't update model on submit before close of modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a search form(search form) rendered inside a modal window(angular ui bootstrap modal). The input fields hold values that update my ng-model on submit.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="mobileSearchPanel">
              <form>
              <h1 style="text-align:center;">Search</h1>
                <div id="mobileSearcher">
                  <div ng-repeat="attobj in columns">
                    <input ng-if="attobj.filterable" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="filterBy1[attobj.filterkey || attobj.key]" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" placeholder="{{ attobj.name }}" ng-enter="cancel()" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input class="phoneSearchSubmitBtn" type="submit" value="submit" style="visibility:hidden;" />
              </form>       

</script>
```

The main controller that wraps the render of the mobileSearchPanel holds the functions for both opening the modal instance( the form) and another to close it:

```
     $scope.showMobileSearchPanel = function (size) {
    //console.log($scope);
    var modalInstxxxance = $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'mobileSearchPanel',
      // controller: 'listController',
      size: size,
      backdrop: true,
      scope: $scope
    });


      $scope.cancel = function(){
        modalInstxxxance.close();
      };
   };
```

To be able to use ng-enter I have the following directive:

```
    // this allows to use on element that holds this directive the following.... ng-enter="myFunction()
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

The issue:

-If I remove ng-enter="cancel()" -> The ng-model updates but in order for a second submit to trigger(re-edit the search) the modal has to be closed and reopen(by clicking outside the modal window)

-If I leave the ng-enter="cancel()" -> The modal closes on press of enter but the submit dosn't go through.

I need the submit and the close to trigger on press of enter or some how solve whatever issue is causing the submit to work only first time and than having to close and reopen the window in between search changes.

The whole issue wouldn't exist if I wouldn't use the "reloadOnSearch:true" in my route path but this I need in order to have the different searches reflected in the browser history. If I would remove this setting the problem would go away but I would loose the different search stages as browser history:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
when("/list/:class", {controller: "listController", templateUrl: "DatabaseObject", reloadOnSearch: true}).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to apply the closing method of the modal on ng-change which is not detected until press of enter thanks to the ng-model-options:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="mobileSearchPanel">


              <form name="search-form">
              <h1 style="text-align:center;">Search</h1>
                <div id="mobileSearcher">
                  <div ng-repeat="attobj in columns">
                    <input ng-if="attobj.filterable" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="filterBy[attobj.filterkey || attobj.key]" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit'}" placeholder="{{ attobj.name }}" ng-change="closingModal()" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input class="phoneSearchSubmitBtn" type="submit" value="submit"  />
              </form>       


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use ng-enter? Why not use ng-submit on the form?

```
<form name="search-form" ng-submit="doSearchThing()">
```

I would also move the function to close the modal to the modal controller. That is why the modal comes with `close` and `dismiss` functions on it.

On a side note, semantically it seems strange to use 'cancel' on enter.

Comment: For some reason with my current config ng-submit doesn't kick in, but I found a solution